# Thymeleaf Spring updating table without reloading page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a table with some rows that need to be updated every x seconds.
A row keeps on asking for updates until it receive a certain value.

I've already read something on fragments but I need more specific examples.

I want to learn how to achieve this behaviour without using javascript/AJAX (I already know them).

```
<table>
     <tr> <!--If simulation.completed=false, this row need to be updated-->
        <td th:text="${simulation.completed}"></td> <!--(true or false)-->  
        <td .... </td> <td>....
     </tr>
     <tr> <!--If simulation.completed=false, this row need to be updated-->
        <td th:text="${simulation.completed}"></td> <!--(true or false)-->  
        <td .... </td> <td>....
     </tr>
     <tr> <!--If simulation completed=false, this row need to be updated-->
        <td th:text="${simulation.completed}"></td> <!--(true or false)-->  
        <td .... </td> <td>....
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with only Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf is server-side. It will render the page and your application sends the page to the client. You will need to use client-side scripts like JavaScript to do this.